# How to hide soft keyboard for one of the EditText when soft keyboard is already shown?

Tags: android, hide, android-softkeyboard

Here the situation: I am showing a screen with 4 input fields, 2 of them need to be edit by user (numeric field), other (text field)- shows some text info which can be changed by user via ListView, but it closed for manual edit.
I use in my XML file `android:editable="false"` for non-numeric EditText fields and it helps to disable popup of soft keyboard when the user click on field. But the problem is in when the user edit a numeric field the soft keyboard not hidding after user focused on text field.

So how can I hide the already shown soft keyboard when user focused on my text field?

The methods like:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(MEdit1.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

or something like this

```
MetricEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MetricEdit);
MetricEdit.setInputType(0);
```

take no effect.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try putting

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(MEdit1.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

in the onclicklistener for the edittext that is editable

you can also change the numeric edittext's keyboard to have a "done" at the bottom with the following:

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

in the xml for the edittext

Comment: Kevin thanks for idea, but this code not solve a problem. I still need for auto-hide the soft keyboard when user select other text field.

Comment: well in each of the edittext onclicklisteners you can do the hidesoftinputfromwindow line for each of the other edittexts, so that all possible keyboards will be closed except the one that was just opened. it works for me.

Comment: Oh, now finally works. This is my inattention, I posted at the beginning of these lines in the onCreate void, but after I replaced them in the onClickListener for each EditText everything works fine. Thanks Kevin.

Comment: ok can you accept the answer in case someone else is looking for the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

This will help..

```
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);      
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)   
{  
    edittext.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);  
    edittext.setTextIsSelectable(true);  
}
```

Comment: ok, how about sdk_int < 11 ? This solution only for 11 and higher?

Comment: No....the first line 'edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);' is for SDK below 11.....but if u r running the app in Sdk 11 and above the if condition will take over.....so it will work everywhere perfectly..!!...it will hide the keyboard but wont hide the cursor...